# Comparing static variable with DB in Django view?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the below view.

I am looking to say, `if due_date < today`, then your project is late.

I'm not able to get today to print to the screen, so I think I'm doing something wrong. The `todo_list` variables can print.

The `todo_list` is something I loop through in the HTML. The `today` variable will be static.

Can anyone help?

```
def todo(request):
    dt_now = datetime.now()
    target_hour = int(dt_now.strftime('%s')) 
    today = datetime.fromtimestamp(target_hour).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    todo_list = Todo.objects.filter(Q(creator=request.user) | Q(assignee=request.user)).order_by('priority')
    context = {'todo_list' : todo_list, 'today' : today}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

And this is the HTML

```
{% for todo in todo_list %}
  <div class="col-sm-3 mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
            {% if todo.complete is False %}
        <h5 class="card-header">{{ todo.text }}</h5>
        {% else %}
        <h5 class="card-header">{{ todo.text }} <small><span class="badge badge-warning">CLOSED</span></small></h5>
{% endif %}
          <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
<table class="table table-hover">       
        <tr>
        <td>Created By</td>
        <td> {{ todo.today }}
        {% if todo.due > todo.today %}
        OVERDUE
        {% endif %}


</td>
```

This is my todo model

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    taskid = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assignee = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    due = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    usedate = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Can you share your `Todo` model? If you need to store a date, it is better to use a `DateField`.

Comment: Thanks - I've just added that :) - I did try to use a date field, but it caused me a lot of issues that I didn't know how to fix & I had to rebuild the server again

Comment: If you need to filter on dates you'd be much better having a `datefield` so django can build the SQL to do things properly. The alternative would be to pull all objects from the database, read the `due` value, convert it to a date, then filter the list of dates. Issues converting a `CharField` to a `DateField` will be much easier than dealing with that kind of data processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could quite easily get all the objects which had a due date in the past like this;

```
from django.utils.timezone import datetime  # important if using timezones

from .models import Todo

today = datetime.today()

late = Todo.objects.filter(due_date__lt=today)
```

But, you've got a date in a `CharField` so add a new field & run a data migration after the migration to add the field, something like this;

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    taskid = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    assignee = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    due = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()
    project = models.CharField(max_length=400, default="none")

    @property
    def is_late(self):
        from datetime import datetime
        if self.due_date < datetime.today()
            return True
        return False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Then you'd create a migration, run the migration, then create an empty migration for your data migration which may end up looking like this;

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.db import migrations, models

def update_due_dates(apps, schema_editor):
    Todo = apps.get_model("appname", "Todo")
    for todo in Todo.objects.all():
        try:
            todo.due_date = datetime.strptime(todo.due, '%Y%m%d')
            todo.save()
        except (AttributeError, TypeError) as e:
            print("Problem with due column ({}) on todo id {}".format(
                todo.due, todo.id))

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('appname', '0002_add_due_date'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(update_due_dates),
    ]
```

So your template would become;

```
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
                <table class="table table-hover">       
                <tr>
                    <td>Created By</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ todo.today }}
                        {% if todo.is_late %}
                            OVERDUE
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Based on your feedback I have added a dateField to my model. I want to be able to print on each task whether it is or isn't overdue - so filtering won't solve that problem. I was hoping in the HTML to add {% if duedate > today %} and do the logic like that - is it possible?

Comment: @kikee1222 well that filter was an example, as you can see I also provided an example of an `is_late` property on the model which you can use in the template.